# Ember-Validations - Don't validate automatically

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-validations to validate a model in a form.

If I create the record with createRecord the instance of the model is already validated and therefore the form already shows validations errors before the user inputs values.

I just want to validate the model before submitting the form. Is there a way?

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this. You can validate the form before it saves the model, and roll it back if invalid. Can you maybe post how you are currently going about it? It's generally easier to modify someone's code than to write an example from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a conditional validator ('if' or 'unless') and activate it only when submitting the form.

Here is a quick example: http://jsbin.com/letujimu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative to ember-validations. [ember-model-validator](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator), with this addon you decide when to validate. By including **Ember-model-validator's** mixin into your model, this will add a `validate` function to your model, it is a synchronous function which returns either true or false.

There is support for all these validations:

- [Presence](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#presence)
- [Acceptance](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#acceptance)
- [Absence](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#absence)
- [Format](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#format)
- [Length](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#length)
- [Email](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#email)
- [Color](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#hex-color)
- [ZipCode](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#zipcode)
- [Subdomain](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#subdomain)
- [URL](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#url)
- [Inclusion](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#inclusion)
- [Exclusion](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#exclusion)
- [Numericality](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#numericality)
- [Match](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#match)
- [Password](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#password)
- [CustomValidation](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#custom)
- [Relations](https://github.com/esbanarango/ember-model-validator#relations)

Example:

```js
// Your model
import Validator from '../mixins/model-validator';

export default DS.Model.extend(Validator, {
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  passwordConfirmation: DS.attr('string'),

  validations: {
    email: {
      presence: true,
      email: { message: 'is not a valid email' }
    },
    password: {
      presence: true,
      length: {
        minimum: 6
      }
    },
    passwordConfirmation: {
      presence: true,
      match: 'password'
    }
  }
});
```

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend(
  {
    actions: {
      saveFakeModel: function() {
        var _this = this,
            fakeModel = this.get('model');

        if(fakeModel.validate()){
          fakeModel.save().then(
            // Success
            function() {
              // Alert success
              console.log('ooooh yeah we just saved the FakeModel...');
            },

            // Error handling
            function(error) {
              // Alert failure
              console.log('There was a problem saving the FakeModel...');
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
        }else{
          fakeModel.get('errors');
        }
      },
    }
  }
);
```